# css div outside of div

Tags: html, css

Sorry to ask for css help again but I really can't get this one. My issue is that a sub div goes outside of an upper div's region. I tried using:

```
display: inline-block;`
```

but that makes the outer div go crazy.

My Problem:
[image]

There is a div with the id of sidebar, which contains the left boxes. which is inside another div with the id of main.

html:

```
<div id="main">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div id="box">
                    <h3>Recently Uploaded</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">402 Base</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">heli mod</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">mw2 menu 1.14</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">402 Base</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">heli mod</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">mw2 menu 1.14</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">402 Base</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">heli mod</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">mw2 menu 1.14</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">402 Base</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                             ...
```

css:

```
#main
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#sidebar
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

#box
{
    /* min-width: 12em; idk if I wanted this */
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}

#box p
{
    padding: 10px;
}

#box h3
{
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#box ul
{
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#box ul li
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

anything I can do? :(

Comment: You could add http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Used to this way http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/ADMKf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
display:table; /* TO our main ID */
```

Comment: You could also add `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow:visible;` to #main as well.  That will fix it for you as well.

Comment: Yes, but it would be take too long has explain ;-)

Comment: Normally, floating elements are taken out of the normal flow of the document, so the containers will not see the floating children's dimensions when calculating it's own dimensions (height/width).  There is a few ways to get the parent container to see the floating children, one is to change the overflow property to hidden or visible.  Another is to use clearing divs after the floats, which will work for height issues as the clearing divs are then moved to just after the floats.  A final issue is to use a combination of both, and create a class called `clearfix` which uses the pseudo elements.

Comment: `clearfix` classes will typically have something like `.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{content:" ";display:table;} .clearfix:after{clear:both}` or some such, and then you would add the clearfix class to the container.  This creates an invisible element just inside the container that will cause it to expand to fit the floats as well, and is commonly used in most frameworks like bootstrap.

Comment: I forgot, the clearfix usually also has this `.clearfix{*zoom: 1;}` in addition to the above to support IE 6/7 as well.

Answer (score 2):

A solution which should work cross-browser and have extremely good browser support would be to apply the following to your `#main` div:

```css
#main{
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Using this will force any floated elements to be calculated into the container's height when drawing its background, borders, etc.

Comment: With my css (probably shitty), this just cuts of the sub div. display: table; is all I could use to get it to work.

Comment: @Jakes625 Possibly try `overflow: auto` or `overflow: visible`, as per Robert's suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `float: left;` to `#main`

Comment: I'll try and report back

Comment: http://puu.sh/3E2pM/6c79edc6c3.jpg that moves it to the left and completely ignores the margin-left and margin-right auto